# VS2015 build with Cordova-cli@5.4.0 shows deployment errors

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Currently, I upgrade my VS2015 Tools for Apache Cordova to update 4, in this version run @5.3.3 well, but change taco.json to run @5.4.0(the newly version) will get the error as follow. It looks like "org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.io.IOException" gradle error.

My question does taco.json support the newly @5.4.0 as well?

[image]

```
    2>  
    2>  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    2>  
    2>  Total time: 3.272 secs
    2>Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
    2>  Built the following apk(s):
    2>      D:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
    2>  Using apk: D:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
    2>  Installing app on device...
    2>  Launching application...
    2>  LAUNCH SUCCESS
    2>  Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "D:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --buildConfig=D:\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\build.json"
    2>  Executing "after_run"  hook for all plugins.
    2>  
    2>Exception in thread "DisconnectableInputStream source reader" org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
    ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio at Microsoft.

We are interpreting the Cordova output from 5.4.0 incorrectly. We think it's telling us there was an error when there actually wasn't one.

We'll fix this in the next update, but for now you can just click "Yes" on that dialog and ignore the warning since there wasn't actually a problem.

Thanks for reporting this to us!

Comment: Not I got it. Thanks anyway. I'll use current version @5.3.3.

Comment: That's probably a good workaround for now. The main thing in 5.4.0 is support for node 5.